# Error parsing XML (Some annoying issue, beginner)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview

I've been looking in the previous subjects about that error, they said that I should list the android:xmlns attirbute first, that's what I've done but I'm still facing that error, no idea why. (It doesn't matter if I copy another layout from a working one).
Here's the XML anyway:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="*CENSORED*"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: And what's the error already?

Comment: @Alex Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Comment: Please post complete XML and complete error/stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: Had to reset my adb..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"    
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll"
            android:apiKey="*******"    />           
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my xml and it works with me. I think you are missing first line.

Comment: It wasn't the correct answer, I had to reset my adb, but I'll accept your answer anyhow.

Comment: @idish So you should wait two days, post your solution and accept it. What's the point in accepting an answer just because it's the only one? Moreover, this can be misleading for people coming here from Google. You also have the option to remove your question

Comment: @Raffaele Okay, I'll just post my own answer for it in a 2 days then, looks like I can't delete it because someone already answered.

Comment: Yes I agreed with both of you.